# balanceOf definition creating a token

Tags: solidity, tokens

When creating a simple token, this code is suggested in the Ethereum website:

```
contract MyToken {

    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    function MyToken(uint256 initialSupply) {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;// Give the creator all
    }
}
```

This works as expected in the testnet (the creator receive the tokens), but if you change the name of `balanceOf` to, let's say, `balances`, the contract does not send the token to the creator (or the mist wallet does not see them).

It happen to be that balanceOf is the name of a function in the ERC20 standard interface (https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard). However, in this code it is defined as a variable.

Any explanation? Is solidity assuming things based on the name of the variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `public` keyword in `mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf` will let the compiler create a public getter function with the same name.

Comment: this means balanceOf is a reserved name?, I am having problems understanding why changing the name of the variable will change the behavior of the contract.

Comment: If ERC20, the caller is expecting a predefined set of functions (balanceOf being one of them), otherwise the implementation is not compliant with ERC20.